# Download all files from a GameFront category

Tags: download

Me and a couple of friends are planning a gaming weekend and one game that we really enjoy is Joint Operations. We would like to try out alot of addon maps and I found a nice category on GameFront, the problem is just that you have to click on every single one of the files and then after that you have to click a download button before the actual download starts.

As far as I can tell there seem to be an ID number connected to each file and you can extract it from the "Download" buttons in the linked page.

> www.gamefront.com/files/**3669617**/__BGB___Castle_Sweep

and then on the next page, on the big "Download" button you can find the same ID number used:

> www.gamefront.com/files/service/thankyou?id=**3669617**

The last page is a countdown page where they, after a few seconds, will finally send you along to the actual file.

Has anyone managed to create a script to handle that?

I don't have enough knowledge in scripting languages yet and if someone already has something working it feels unecessary to reinvent the wheel ;)

Thank you!

[GameFront category (Joint Operations - Coop)](http://www.gamefront.com/files/listing/gamingfiles/Joint_Operations/Maps/Co-Op)

**EDIT:**
This is how I eventually solved it:

**`download_files.js`**

```
report = "";
for (i = 1; i < 300; i=i+2) {
  iimDisplay("Step "+(i+1));
  iimSet("FILELOOP", i);
  retcode = iimPlay("download_file");
  if (retcode < 0) {
    report += ": "+iimGetLastError();
    alert ( report );
  }
}
```

**`download_file.iim`**

```
VERSION BUILD=7210419 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1     
'URL GOTO=http://www.gamefront.com/files/listing/gamingfiles/Joint_Operations/Maps/Co-Op
URL GOTO=http://unblockwebnow.info/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nYW1lZnJvbnQuY29tL2ZpbGVzL2xpc3RpbmcvZ2FtaW5nZmlsZXMvSm9pbnRfT3BlcmF0aW9ucy9NYXBzL0NvLU9w&hl=3ed

WAIT SECONDS=1

TAG POS={{FILELOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TITLE:Download<SP>This<SP>File
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:downloadLink
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE={{!EXTRACT}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:click<SP>here
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

I noticed that my country was on their block list, that is why I am using a proxy to download the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/). There you can write a script which actually clicks on buttons and waits during the delay period. You can make it behave like a real user. Here's a [tutorial](http://wiki.imacros.net/Tutorials).

If you can handle some basic vbs scripting in Excel, then this should come relatively easy.